# Django 1.8: "./manage.py test" fails with TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'

Tags: django-testing, django-1.8

```
(mathspace)pzrq@Peters-Mac-mini:~/Projects/mathspace$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default' (':memory:')...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 20, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_without_migrations/management/commands/test.py", line 28, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle(*test_labels, **options)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/Users/pzrq/.virtualenvs/mathspace/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 365, in create_test_db
    verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by:

```
pip uninstall django-test-without-migrations
```

I'd guess this is caused by older versions of [django-test-without-migrations](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/) not respecting the optparse to argparse update in Django 1.8, so I later determined you can also fix it with:

```
pip install --upgrade django-test-without-migrations
```